# Does the Hugginface NER pipeline internally deal with long documents?

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, huggingface-transformers

My set up looks as follows:

```
MODEL_CHECKPOINT = "distilroberta-base"
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(PATH_TO_MY_MODEL, max_len=512, add_prefix_space=True)
model = AutoModelForTokenClassification.from_pretrained(MODEL_CHEKPOINT, num_labels=32)
ner_pipeline = pipeline(task="ner", tokenizer=tokenizer, model=model)
```

However I can obtain the NER predictions for an arbitrary length documents. I wonder how is it implemented internally (maybe sliding window approach?)

Answer (score 0):

In fact, the tokenizer argument in the pipeline class constructor determines how it deals with the length of the input document. Every `**kwarg` related to the tokenizing step (which would be performed before feeding the document to the model) can be set like below.

```
MODEL_CHECKPOINT = "distilroberta-base"
ner_pipeline = pipeline(task="ner", tokenizer=(MODEL_CHECKPOINT, {'model_max_length': 128}), model=model)
```

for your case (leaving tokenizer as it is) model would chop/pad input document to the length of `tokenizer.model_max_length` which is equal to `512`.